# YugabyteDB Can't assign requested address

Tags: yugabytedb

I am trying to start yugabyteDB locally with the following command:

```
./bin/yb-ctl destroy && ./bin/yb-ctl —ref 3
```

But yb-master and yb-tserver is not up.

Checking logs, I see:

```
cat yb-master.FATAL
Log file created at: 2022/12/16 13:41:38
Current UTC time: 2022/12/16 18:41:38
Running on machine: Deniss-MBP.lan
Application fingerprint: version 2.17.0.0 build 24 revision d4f01a5e26b168585e59f9c1a95766ffdd9655b1 build_type RELEASE built at 16 Nov 2022 00:19:06 GMT
Running duration (h:mm:ss): 0:00:00
Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
F1216 13:41:38.916921 2966208 master_main.cc:131] Network error (yb/util/net/socket.cc:325): Error binding socket to 127.0.0.2:7100: Can't assign requested address (system error 49)
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that you need to configure the network interfaces 127.0.0.2 and 127.0.0.3 to get it working.
Use these commands to create the interfaces and then start the cluster:

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.2 up
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.3 up
```